# Swift - Is there a way to include single quotes (') in a concatenated string?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have already searched for answers and whatever I tried unfortunately did not work.
My case is as follows:
I have an array of keywords and I am building an `NSPredicate` in order to filter data from CoreData. The code below:

```
var strKeywordsOrFilter = "(1 == 1)" //just an initial {true} statement to assist with the OR conditional
for intIndex in 0...pInputWords.count - 1
{
    let strKeyword = "'" + pInputWords[intIndex] + "'"
    strKeywordsOrFilter = strKeywordsOrFilter + " OR (imageDescr CONTAINS[c] " + strKeyword + ")"
}
```

`imageDescr` is one of the entity attributes in my CoreData.
What I want to accomplish is to create a concatenated string of OR conditions for as many keywords exist in the array `pInputWords`.
When I debug print the variable `strKeywordsOrFilter` it does NOT contain any backslashes before any single quote character, e.g.

```
(1 == 1) OR (imageDescr CONTAINS[c]  'camping') OR (imageDescr CONTAINS[c]  'lake')
```

but the same variable when it reaches the "predicate" command, it contains backslashes before every single quote, e.g.

```
(1 == 1) OR (imageDescr CONTAINS[c]  \'camping\') OR (imageDescr CONTAINS[c]  \'lake\')
```

I have tried a number of workarounds but nothing seems to get rid of the "\".
Any help would be appreciated because I am really stuck!

Comment: What do you mean by "when it reaches the "predicate" command"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to manually construct your query, or worry about quotes. You can use a compound predicate instead and standard [predicate formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) (`%@` for values and `%K` for keys):

```
let predicates = pInputWords.map { word in
    NSPredicate(format: "imageDescr CONTAINS[c] %@", word)
}

let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

// Which gives:
// imageDescr CONTAINS[c] "camping" OR imageDescr CONTAINS[c] "lake"
```

ps. Your query string produces the same result when fed to a predicate, which seems to be fine

Comment: Hi Alladinian, EXCELLENT solution. It works great. Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: @sugarakis Thanks for the kind words! I’m glad that helped you.